# Paper Button cannot be disabled

Tags: android

I am creating an android app with this library:
https://github.com/keithellistemp/MaterialWidget

This library contains "Paper Button" widget.
I wanted to disable it, so I tried in several ways.

```
pBtn_regist.setClickable(false);
```

or

```
pBtn_regist.setEnabled(false);
```

However there had no effect...

I have no idea how to disable it.

Comment: Probably its author would be the best person to answer this question

Comment: @Zielony Thank you for your reply. I really think so too, but I don't have any ways to contact the author...